# indexOutOfBounds when resuming activity

Tags: android

I am using this to populate some fields from a database.

```
private void populateField() {

if(mRowId != null ){

    Cursor Message = mDbHelper.fetchScheduledTask(mRowId);
    startManagingCursor(Message);
    Log.e("ROWID", mRowId.toString());
    String commaText = (Message.getString(Message.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SmsDbAdapter.KEY_NUMBERS)));
    numbers.setText(commaText);
```

When the activity is paused then resumed i get the error

```
10-17 11:15:13.123: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15432): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

It points to this line of code.

```
String commaText = (Message.getString(TextMessage.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SmsDbAdapter.KEY_NUMBERS)));
```

How can i get rid or be defensive against this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the cursor is empty before using it.

```
if (Message.moveToFirst()) {
    String commaText = (Message.getString(Message.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SmsDbAdapter.KEY_NUMBERS)));
    numbers.setText(commaText);
    // Whatever else you want to do with the cursor
}
```

moveToFirst() will return false if there are no items in the cursor.

Comment: Fixed small typo - you were checking for 'not' (!Message.moveToFirst()) ... removed the ! ... if the cursor is able to move to the first position, there's valid rows in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void populateField() {

    if(mRowId != null ){

        Cursor Message = mDbHelper.fetchScheduledTask(mRowId);
        try{
           if(Message != null && Message.moveToNext()){
                startManagingCursor(Message);
                Log.e("ROWID", mRowId.toString());
                String commaText = Message.getString(Message.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SmsDbAdapter.KEY_NUMBERS)));
                numbers.setText(commaText);
            }
        }finally{
            if(Message != null){
                try{
                   Message.close();
                } catch(Exception e){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want you could even throw a catch before the finally :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a try/catch block if you don't like to test with ifs like coder_for_life proposed

```
private void populateField() {

if(mRowId != null ){
    Cursor Message = mDbHelper.fetchScheduledTask(mRowId);
    startManagingCursor(Message);
    Log.e("ROWID", mRowId.toString());
    try{
        String commaText = (Message.getString(Message.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SmsDbAdapter.KEY_NUMBERS)));
    }catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        //do something to handle the error
    }
    numbers.setText(commaText);
```